# remove lines with sed and regexp

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file that looks like this:

```
rs994321    -   chr6_ssto_hap7  712891  G   A   0.011180599999999999        0.0058201   62357
rs994321    -   chr6_mcf_hap5   675532  G   A   0.011180599999999999    0.0058201   62357
rs994321    -   chr6_mann_hap4  675338  G   A   0.011180599999999999    0.0058201   62357
rs994321    -   chr4_dbb_hap3   675681  G   A   0.011180599999999999    0.0058201   62357
rs994321    -   chr4_cox_hap2   891136  G   A   0.011180599999999999    0.0058201   62357
rs994321    -   chr6    29372356    G   A   0.011180599999999999    0.0058201   62357
rs9943219   +   chr1    238691947   A   G   0.00700761  0.00727069  62357
rs9943217   +   chr1    238691673   A   G   0.00663929  0.00715566  62357
```

I would like to remove the lines with the pattern `chr*_*_hap*`. Only the last 3 lines should remain in my example. I have tried with the following commands but they don't work:

```
sed '/chr[0-9]_*_hap[0-9]/d' test.txt
sed '/*_hap[0-9]/d' test.txt
sed '/\*_hap[0-9]/d' test.txt
```

I not very good using regexp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ egrep -v '\bchr([^_]*_){2}hap[0-9]\b' data
rs994321    -   chr6    29372356    G   A   0.011180599999999999    0.0058201   62357
rs9943219   +   chr1    238691947   A   G   0.00700761  0.00727069  62357
rs9943217   +   chr1    238691673   A   G   0.00663929  0.00715566  62357
```

or using `sed`:

```
$ sed -r '/\bchr([^_]*_){2}hap[0-9]\b/d' data
rs994321    -   chr6    29372356    G   A   0.011180599999999999    0.0058201   62357
rs9943219   +   chr1    238691947   A   G   0.00700761  0.00727069  62357
rs9943217   +   chr1    238691673   A   G   0.00663929  0.00715566  62357
```

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk '! /chr[^_]*_[^_]*_hap[0-9]/' data
rs994321    -   chr6    29372356    G   A   0.011180599999999999    0.0058201   62357
rs9943219   +   chr1    238691947   A   G   0.00700761  0.00727069  62357
rs9943217   +   chr1    238691673   A   G   0.00663929  0.00715566  62357
```

Comment: Complete and nice :-)

Comment: The `.*`s at the end of the REs are doing nothing, remove them. Likewise remove the `{print}` from the awk statement. The regexps should really be `chr[^_]*_[^_]*_hap` to be more robust, and that could be reduced to `chr([^_]*_){2}hap` for brevity with most of the commands. You typically should also add anchors and/or identify a specific field but it's probably OK for this format of input.